# book page index effect with pure css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have been trying to get the following done with css with no avail.

[image]

This is the closest I've gotten to something like this.

[image]

As you see, I am close, but no cigar. I need the dashes (or lines preferably, but won't get picky) are not all reaching the number. I tried taking them all the way over and use overflow:hidden, but nothing. And also, this is a responsive site so it has to respect responsiveness as well.

Here is my code. THANKS!! :

HTML

```
      <div class="col-md-12 allocation">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">Equities</div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">65%</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">Domestic large capitalized firms</div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">25%</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">Domestic small capitalized firms</div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">15%</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">International developed markets</div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">15%</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">International emerging markets</div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">10%</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10"><strong>Fixed Income</strong></div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"><strong>15%</strong></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10"><strong>Real Estate</strong></div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"><strong>20%</strong></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">Core</div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">12.5%</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">Timber</div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">7.5%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.allocation .row{
     margin:15px auto;
}
.allocation .row > div.col-md-10.col-sm-10.col-xs-10:after{
     content: "--------------------------------------------------- ";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/paulalexandru/08k1916j/show/), you can check the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/08k1916j/) or here:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div>Equities</div>
        <div>65%</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div>Domestic large capitalized firms</div>
        <div>25%</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div>Domestic small capitalized firms</div>
        <div>15%</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div>International developed markets</div>
        <div>15%</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div>International emerging markets</div>
        <div>10%</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div><strong>Fixed Income</strong></div>
        <div><strong>15%</strong></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div><strong>Real Estate</strong></div>
        <div><strong>20%</strong></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div>Core</div>
        <div>12.5%</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div>Timber</div>
        <div>7.5%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this css code:

```
.row {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
    height: 15px;
    clear: right;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.row div:first-of-type {
    float: left;
    background: #FFF;
    padding-right: 5px;

}

.row div:last-of-type {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1px;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions for this... here is one:

```css
.index-row{
    border-bottom: 1px dashed;  
    height:1.5em;
    clear:both;
 }

.index-row h2, .index-row span{
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
    line-height:1.0em;
    background:white;
}

.index-row h2{
    float:left;
}

.index-row span{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div>
    
    <div class="index-row">
        <h2>titulo indice</h2>
        <span>45</span>
    </div>
     <div class="index-row">
        <h2>titulo indice</h2>
        <span>45</span>
    </div>
     <div class="index-row">
        <h2>titulo indice</h2>
        <span>45</span>
    </div>
    
    
</div>
```

Comment: Good work Joe. It didn't work out for me. I'm guessing some other conflicting code in my css. But I upped it anyway because it worked in your snippet. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple and responsive solution using grid:

```css
.index-item {
     display: grid;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: baseline;
     grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
     gap: .5rem;
     padding-block: .5rem;
}

.index-line {
     height: 3px;
     min-width: 15px;
     background: linear-gradient(90deg, #888 2.5%, #fff 2.5%, #fff 47.5%, #888 47.5%, #888 52.5%, #fff 52.5%, #fff 97.5%, #888 97.5%);
     background-size: 10px 10px;
     background-position: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-item">
    <div class="index-title">Page Title</div>
    <span class="index-line"></span>
    <div class="index-number">200</div>
</div>

<div class="index-item">
    <div class="index-title">Page Title (long title)</div>
    <span class="index-line"></span>
    <div class="index-number">230</div>
</div>
```